# MS Access (or SQL) query: Equivalent of horizontal CountIf()

Tags: sql, ms-access, countif

If I have a set of values like this:

| Field 1 | Field 2 | Field 3 | Field 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B |  | C |
| 2 |  | 4 |  |
|  | x |  | y |

and if I want to know how many non-empty values each row has, in Excel, I could do this:

```
=4 - CountIf(A2:D2, "")
```

Is there a way to do that in a query in MS Access (or SQL in general)?

Answer (score 0):

You would add them up in MS Access:

```
select t.*,
       (iff(field1 is not null, 1, 0) + 
        iff(field2 is not null, 1, 0) + 
        iff(field3 is not null, 1, 0) + 
        iff(field4 is not null, 1, 0)
       ) as num_not_null
from t;
```

Comment: Hmm, that's a lot of code compared to a single function in Excel. I actually have 23 fields to be tested in each row, so I was hoping for something more compact.

Comment: @NewSites . . . That probably means that you should have a table with one row per column -- that is, an unpivoted version of the data.  It sounds like your data model is not optimized for SQL.

Comment: I could easily believe that my data model is not optimized since I'm not an expert at this. Can you edit your answer to explain your suggestion? I Googled `unpivot data` and I don't see how that is going to solve my problem.